# User Entity Accessing Global Variable

Tags: authentication, symfony

I am very new at Symfony2, so please bear with me. I am working on creating a web application where there will be two websites/parent bundles sharing a common bundle. Part of the bundle is my `User` entity model. With these websites, there are subscriptions to be purchased so the user can access the program part of these websites.

I am thinking that the best is to use the `Roles` authorization mechanism. I am running into a problem with that. The problem is that I cannot access variables/services (meaning, my website service, which contains information about the current website session) outside of that entity - and that does make sense. Is there a way to take the standard User (`class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable`) entity that I am using for authentication, and turn it into a service? But that seems to present problems because I am using a custom repository for the `User` class which returns a `User` class.

**So, how can I get external information injected into a `User` entity model?** - I think that is the summary of what I am asking.

### Edit:

This is my class definition for the user class:

```
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
```

Here is my `security.yml` for the website:

```
providers:
    database:
        entity: { class: WebsiteCommonBundle:User }
```

I would like to implement the `getRoles()` function to provide the current roles that the user is a part of. The challenge is that this is dependent on certain criteria to be met (which is different for each website). This information comes from a Symfony service, and it is there, I just don't know how to get that information pushed into the entity.

Comment: Maybe I'm still sleeping, but I don't get your problem :P Please, help me to help you :)

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement a [`UserProvider`](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html) to handle the users and their credentials.

Comment: @Squazic - that was exactly what I needed. If you want to move that to an answer I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just having `Users` isn't enough for assigning roles/access to the web application. To handle that, you'll want to implement a `UserProvider` as well. The [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html) give a pretty good start on the topic.